# locate column location from variable and pass to .range"" code

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the partial code below to locate a borrower's name in a horizontal list. Once I find the name I need to pass the column and be able to reference that column in `range("").value`. So for example it finds the name in column G I can then use the range.value code and some how pair it up with different rows to do copy or do other things with.

```
Sub Copy_From_Borrower_DBase()
    Dim myVal As String
    Dim sourceRng As Range
    myVal = Sheets("Main").Range("F2").Value ' dropdown list
    Set sourceRng = Worksheets("Borrower Database").Range("5:5").Find( _
            What:=myVal, LookAt:=xlWhole) 'locate column where to copy from
    Sheets("Main").Range("F5").Value = Worksheets("Borrower Database"). _
            Range("??????????").Value 'Borrower Name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grab the column from your `sourceRng`, you can simply use the `.Column` property. I personally would use `Cells()` instead of `Range()` since you're dealing with column numbers.

So, in your use case:

```
Worksheets("Main").Range("F5").Value = Worksheets("Borrower Database"). _
        Cells(Row, sourceRng.Column).Value 'Borrower Name
```

Where you would replace `Row` with your corresponding row number.

Comment: Glad to assist!